# How to make div inline but in a specific way?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a html code for creating several small boxes and that box has a name given from an `object(graphdata)`.

```
    <div ng-repeat="a in graphdata" class="inline">

<div class="legend-box"style="background-color:{{a.color}};">
</div>
      <p class="legend-name">
     {{a.projects}}
      </p>
 </div>
   </div>
```

I need to align this boxes in lines, one line should contain only 2 boxes with name.
I will make a demo:

```
  [] box1      [] box2
  [] box3      [] box4
  [] box5      [] box6
```

[] indicate the rectangle and box1, box 2,... are the names of boxes.
the problem is im using ng-repeat. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.inline {
     display: inline-block; /*This is the inline, but different*/
     width: 50%; /*You may add less, to accommodate margins*/
     box-sizing: border-box; /*Gets rid of issues with paddings*/
}
```

Comment: This is the "heart" of any grid system :)

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs, what this is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Use ul li instead of div. And set css property to `ul column-count:2`.

Or you can `float:left` and `width:50%` each div. Its will set divs two column.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your divs and not use ul and lis you can use the Flex-box !

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

But be aware because it is available only on young browser !

You can do that like that :

```
.parent {
 display: flex;
 align-content: flex-start;
}
.child {
 width: 50%;
}
```

Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged the question with `ionic-framework`, I'll base my answer with Ionic framework features.

In [Ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid) you can find examples of using a grid layout.

As a possible solution, you can do it like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="a in graphdata" class="col col-50">
        <div class="legend-box"style="background-color:{{a.color}};"></div>
        <p class="legend-name">{{a.projects}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer would be good, if the OP used a grid system. At this level of knowledge he may or may not know about any.

Comment: So a good answer, which is well documented within the ionic framework, and where the user only needs to add 2 already builtin css classes, but just because It uses grid is a reason for downvoting? lol

Comment: I didn't downvote the question. By the way, the OP doesn't seem to use the ionic framework in thie example, despite the tag. Also my mistake, I missed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to set fixed width and height to the *inline* and *legend-box* classes.

To make it responsive you'll also need to defined these classes for different media queries.